# Swift scroll view last item is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am currently learning swift, and I have a project where I have to display three images by using scroll view, but the problem is that when I scroll over the three image, the scroll view keeps on going how can I only scroll over there images.
here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var images = [UIImageView]()
    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        for x in 0...2 {
            let image = UIImage(named: "icon\(x).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            images.append(imageView)

            var newX: CGFloat = 0.0
            newX = view.frame.midX + view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(x)

            contentWidth += newX

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX - 75, y: (view.frame.size.height / 2) - 75, width: 150, height: 150)

        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.size.height)

    }

}
```

here how it looks like -

First image item -

[image: first image item]

Second image item-

[image: second image item]

Third image item -

[image: third image item]

Fourth item which is not supposed to appear -

[image: fourth item which is not supposed to appear]

Comment: do not use view.frame in viewDidLoad as it might not be correct at that point (before the view has been laid out and frame calculated correctly).

Comment: then what should my code look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a couple of issues:

1. The size of the `view` is not properly established at the time `viewDidLoad()` is called.  Move your code to an `override` of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to make sure you have the correct size of the view.  Be careful though, that routine will be called multiple times, so use a `Boolean` (with a name like `contentAdded`) to keep track if you've already added the content to prevent setting up the `scrollView` more than once.
2. You are incrementing `contentWidth` by the wrong amount.  Each time through the loop, you just want the `contentWidth` to be extended by the width of the `view`.

---

Here is the updated code:

```
var contentAdded = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !contentAdded {
        contentAdded = true

        for x in 0...2 {
            let image = UIImage(named: "icon\(x).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            images.append(imageView)

            var newX: CGFloat = 0.0
            newX = view.frame.midX + view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(x)

            contentWidth += view.frame.size.width

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX - 75, y: (view.frame.size.height / 2) - 75, width: 150, height: 150)

        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

---

**Note:**  You are assuming that the `scrollView` has the same `width` and `height` as the `view`, but this might not always be the case if you were to layout your screen differently.  It would be more correct to use `scrollView.bounds` instead of `view.frame` so that you would get the expected results even if you made your `scrollView` smaller than the screen.

Comment: Thank you so much man your answer was right and I really appreciate you for helping me.